# Modules in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm looking to make an app similar to snapchat which requires me to open the app to the homescreen, then swipe one way for the camera.
To make an app with multiple windows, do I have to create two modules: one for the homepage and one for the camera?

Comment: I don't think your use of the word "module" makes sense here. Gradle has modules to manage Android Studio projects, but that's unrelated to the camera

Comment: Do you know how I could create a multi-page app then? As in, where do I go to separate these codes into their own pages on the app.

Answer (score 0):

> To make an app with multiple windows, do I have to create two modules

You could, but it's simply two Fragments or Activities in one application, so you don't have to, no. It'd be simpler not to also

> swipe one way for the camera

Do some research into the `ViewPager` class

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll look into this.